# Can't aggregate new columns

Tags: powerbi

I created new columns from if/then/else formulas where the output is either a number or null, but I can't aggregate them without getting an error saying that this new column that I'm trying to aggregate is a string. What can be the possible causes for this?

Comment: provide more details in your post. Where do you create this new column and how you do aggregation? In transformation tab (M - Language), or in DAX (on the main canva).

Comment: Created them in the transformation tab. Trying to aggregate them in the report in DAX. I created them with this kind of formula = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom44", "Pure Connect Res", each if [Product Sales TGT] = "Pure Connect Res" then 1 else if [Product Sales TGT] = "Conventional Line Res" then 1 else 0)

Comment: Okay thank you. I didn't know that you need to manually choose the data type for every column after creating it in Transformation. It seems to work

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually choose the Data Type for every column after creating it in Transformation.